ADC producing strange behaviour when pulling pin low
Problem: I have designed a custom data acquisition board centered around the MAX11046 ADC. The ADC is controlled entirely with an STM32 development board. I have implemented the MAX11046's parallel interface in code, and have successfully been able to read data from a single channel. Additionally, the current draw of the ADC circuit when functioning correctly is ~74mA.
The problem comes when I attempt to advance the channel, which requires pulling both CS and RD low. For some reason, this shuts down the ADC: the current consumption drops to ~35mA; the ADC no longer responds to communication; there is no output on the REFIO pin. Note that SHDN is wired to ground the entire time and all inputs stay floating.
Powering the ADC board on-and-off does not fix the problem. Only when I disconnect the USB power to the STM32 board, then power on-and-off the ADC does everything return to normal --that is, until I pull CS and/or RD low again, repeating the same behaviour.
Here is a very basic block diagram for how everything is wired up:

All the grounds are connected together.
Here is the simplified code, which runs once on button press:
    convst.set_high();

    cs.set_high();
    rd.set_high();

    // Wait 1s after initialization
    delay.delay_ms(1000u32);

    hprintln!("Init Complete");

    // Start the conversion
    convst.set_low();

    delay.delay_us(1u32);

    convst.set_high();

    // Wait until conversion is complete
    while eoc.is_high() {
        hprintln!("EOC is High");
    }

    hprintln!("Completed");

    // Start reading tha data
    convst.set_low();

    cs.set_low();

    let mut code: u16 = 0;

    for i in 0..8usize {
        rd.set_low();

        hprintln!("Channel: {}", i);

        delay.delay_us(1u32);

        code = 0;

        for (n, bit) in bus.iter().enumerate() {
            if bit.is_high() {
                code = code | (1 << n);
            }
        }

        hprintln!("Reading: {:?}", code);

        rd.set_high();

        delay.delay_us(1u32);
    }

    rd.set_high();
    cs.set_high();

    delay.delay_us(1u32);

    convst.set_high();

Here is the timing diagram of what the code should be doing (after the "initialization"):

Unfortunately, I don't have a logic analyzer, so I can't capture everything at once. However, I did check each of the signals manually with an oscilloscope, and it appears to be working.
The status LEDs for power on the ADC board are on despite the power supply being off. In fact, my power supply is detecting ~1.1V. The only source of power here is the USB from my computer, though it only shares a common ground with the circuit.

**
As I take it, current must be leaking from the STM32 pins and through the ADC somehow?
All of this abnormal behaviour only occurs as a result of triggering the strange state via pulling the CS and/or RD pin(s) low. When functioning normally, nothing "leaks"; the LEDs stay off when ADC board power is cut and I get no erroneous voltage readings.
Ideas: I suspect that by either design or damage, there is somehow a connection across the CS and/or RD pin(s), the STM32 GPIOs and power. Perhaps when they are pulled to ground, it shorts the power supply through the ADC and STM32. This would also explain why the ADC board is still "powered" even though its main supply is off. However, I checked the signal on the CS and RD pins during this weird state, and they were at ground.
Alternatively, maybe there is an issue with SHDN and ground?
I am aware that the inputs of the MAX11046 are clamped and protected; is it possible that something is going on at the input? Even so, the maximum voltage present is still only 5V, which is completely in specification.
Do forgive me if this is something obvious.
Note: Those interested in the schematics of the ADC board can find it here

Can you show a timing diagram of what you're doing, and compare to Figs 6/7 in https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX11044-MAX11056.pdf??

@ScottSeidman Sure thing, I'll update the question with more information.

I figured I'd answer the question just in case anyone ever happens to come across a similar problem.
After some more testing, questions and help from Analog Devices themselves, the problem turned out to be bus contention. Since the MAX11046 uses the same data lines to both send and receive data, the WR pin needs to be high during read mode --I was keeping it low.
Additionally, the LEDs stay illuminated because when the main power is turned off, there is leak through the ESD protection diodes of the IC. The full question I asked covering this can be found here.
